# The meaning of "I Owe, Therefore I Am"

Tags: expressions

Hello: What is the meaning of "I Owe, Therefore I Am" in the following title? -

"[I Owe, Therefore I Am: The Impossibility of Imagining a Post-Debt US](https://goldsilver.com/blog/i-owe-therefore-i-am-the-impossibility-of-imagining-a-post-debt-us/)"

Does it refer to someone owing someone something? Thanks!

Comment: Having debt **is** owing someone something (money). Are you familiar with [Descartes’ famous phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito,_ergo_sum)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The famous phrase from the philosopher Descartes is "I think, therefore I am" which originally denoted that the minimum evidence for the existence of a self is that the self thinks. It has been changed many times as a pun to succinctly state the importance of various things. In this case, presumably, the author is making a case for either the importance of debt or the universality of debt.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Zy20Jo0VVbs?t=63

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It's just such a girly odd expression - I don't think I'll ever be able to use it in the right context.